# capitalize first letter in file

Tags: c, file-io, letters

I'm trying to capitalize first letter. The chars are read from text file. Unfortunately, I can't. I read an idea it says add two boolean variables, which could be of type int: one variable will hold 1 when the current character is part of a word, the other variable will hold 1 when the previous character is part of a word. But, how can I know whether char is part of word or not ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cpt(char x[]);

int main(){

    cptlz("in.txt");

    return 0;
}
void cptlz(char x[]){

    char ch;

    int currentch,
        previouschar,
        st=1;

    FILE *fptr_in;

    if((fptr_in=fopen(x,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error reading file\n");
    }
    else{
        while(st==1){
            st=fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch);
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            printf("%c",ch-32);
        }
            else
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) and [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper).

Comment: A simple way would be to check if the previous char is a space, newline, special charakter,... and the current is a letter... That means you are at the beginning of a word (be carefull, also "... a word" woukd lead to "... A Word")

Comment: Think about it.  First work out which characters are found in words and which are not.

Comment: What is your function supposed to do? You have different names for it, its parameter `x` does not seem to be used, ... Please organize your question *and* your code before asking here. Voting to close.

Comment: Also note that [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and family) using the `"%s"` format reads *space* delimited "words".

Comment: JoachimPileborg i can't use ctype.h bluepixy how can I make it ? Besides, I can't use %s :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this code..

```
void cptlz(char x[]){

char ch;

int currentch,
    previouschar='\n',
    st=1;

FILE *fptr_in;

if((fptr_in=fopen(x,"r"))==NULL){
    printf("Error reading file\n");
}
else{

    while((ch=fgetc(fptr_in))!=EOF){

    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' && (previouschar=='\n' || previouschar==' ')){
        printf("%c",ch-32);
    }
        else
            printf("%c",ch);

    previouschar=ch;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That will not "capitalize first letter of every word" but the first letter of every *line*.

Comment: The OP does not mention any specific format for "words", so the following may be an unnecessary improvement; but your code will not capitalize the first character of a word between parentheses. (Think of an alternative way to check, rather than adding `(` to your list. No worries, you're on the right track.)

Comment: This code is for giving an idea for the person who asked question. I understood your point.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

A character is "part of a word" and should be capitalized if:

1. it is a lowercase character `a..z` (for which you can, and probably *should*, use the standard library function `islower`), and
2. the *previous* character was *not* a letter -- capital or lowercase (which can be tested by the standard library function `isalpha`).

So you have to remember the "last state" (encountered *any* letter); when the *current* character is another letter *and* the last one was not, you must uppercase it. (In principle you can use `isalpha` here as well, but you only need to check if it is a *lowercase* letter because if it already is an uppercase, you don't have to change it.)

After outputting the character (changed or not), save it as the new state for `lastWasLetter`. I changed the name and function from the original `previouschar`, because you don't really need to test the actual value -- you only need to know if it was a letter or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void cptlz (const char *x);

int main(){

    cptlz("in.txt");

    return 0;
}

void cptlz (const char *input_filename)
{
    int ch, lastWasLetter = 0;

    FILE *fptr_in;

    fptr_in = fopen (input_filename,"r");
    if(fptr_in == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error reading file '%s'\n", input_filename);
        return;
    }
    while ( (ch = fgetc (fptr_in)) != EOF )
    {
        if (!lastWasLetter && islower(ch))
            ch = toupper(ch);
        printf ("%c",ch);
        lastWasLetter = isalpha(ch);
    }
    fclose (fptr_in);
}
```